# floppy fstab entry for vfat and ext

Tags: linux, mount, floppy, fstab

I'm trying to create an fstab entry for /dev/fd0 so that user can mount a floppy formatted either with VFAT or ext32. The simple fstab entry

```
/dev/fd0 /mnt/floppy auto noauto,user,sync,gid=users,umask=000 0 2
```

can only mount DOS floppies. If I change the entry to

```
/dev/fd0 /mnt/floppy ext2 noauto,user,sync 0 2
```

then I can only mount a floppy with ext2 filesystem.
Obviously, I can issue a root mount command with appropriate -t option and mount either floppies. Is there a way to mount floppy as user with the simple command

```
mount /mnt/floppy
```

for floppies with either VFAT or ext2 filesystem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man 8 mount` on Linux:

> If  no  `-t`  option  is  given, or if the `auto` type is specified,
>   mount will try to guess the desired type.  Mount uses the  `blkid`
>   library  for guessing the filesystem type; if that does not turn
>   up anything that looks familiar, mount will try to read the file
>   `/etc/filesystems`, or, if that does not exist, `/proc/filesystems`. 
>   All of the filesystem types listed there will be  tried,  except
>   for  those that are labeled `nodev` (e.g. `devpts`, `proc` and `nfs`).
>   If `/etc/filesystems` ends in a line with a single `*`,  `mount`  will
>   read `/proc/filesystems` afterwards.  While trying, all filesystem
>   types will be mounted with the mount option `silent`.

So just create a file `/etc/filesystems` containing something like this:

```
ext4
ext3
ext2
vfat
msdos
ntfs
iso9660
ufs
xfs
```

Add more filetypes if you need.  Then you can use type `auto` in `fstab`.

Comment: @Sato Katsura - thanks for your interest in responding to my question. I do have the `/etc/filesystems` file that contains ext2 and vfat entries, yet fstab with auto entry gives error suach as "bad superblock..." if using `mount` command without -t option. The `cat /proc/filesystem` shows only filesystems currently used by mounted devices. This problem happens only with `/dev/fd0`; I can mount auto sda devices (usb sticks formatted either vfat or ext2). Strange behavior for fd0?

Comment: @Janos The order is important, the entries are tried in order.  If `msdos` comes before `vfat` and you try to mount a `vfat` filesystem you'll get an error, because the filesystems are similar enough for `msdos` to match.

Comment: @sato Katsura - it works now! Thanks again, Janos